# Selecting IDs linked with CPC codes in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the PATSTAT database to select the APPLN_ID of patent applications that have a cpc classification symbol but not another. I need to do this in order to retrieve a control dataset of patents to verify my hypothesis.

PATSTAT is a relational database where each patent application has a set of attributes. The TLS224 table contains multiple rows with the same APPLN_ID and different CPC symbols. I want to retrieve the APPLN_IDs that have a set of symbols A but that do not have a set of symbols B.

From this example data

```
| APPLN_ID | CPC_CLASS_SYMBOL |
| 2345     | C07K  16/26      |
| 2345     | C07K2317/34      |
| 2345     | C07K2317/76      |
| 2345     | G01N  33/74      |
| 2345     | B01L   9/527     |
| 1000     | C07K2317/34      |
| 1000     | C07K  16/26      |
| 1000     | C07K2317/76      |
| 1000     | B01L   3/5025    |
| 9999     | B01L   3/5025    |
| 9999     | G01N2333/47      |
| 9999     | G01N2333/4727    |
```

I want to obtain this as a result.

```
| APPLN_ID |
| 1000     |
```

Here, the set of values A that must be included are 'C07K  16/26' ,'C07K2317/34', 'C07K2317/76', while the value B that must NOT be present is G01N  33/74.

How can I do that?

This is what I came out with so far (I know that the WHERE IN and NOT IN clauses nullify each other, but it is just to show an example).

```
SELECT DISTINCT p2.APPLN_ID
FROM (SELECT p1.APPLN_ID, p1.PUBLN_AUTH, YEAR(p1.PUBLN_DATE)
        FROM TLS211_PAT_PUBLN p1
            WHERE YEAR(p1.PUBLN_DATE) = 2008
                    AND PUBLN_AUTH = 'WO') p2
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT cpc3.APPLN_ID
            FROM TLS224_APPLN_CPC cpc3
            WHERE cpc3.APPLN_ID IN 
                (SELECT APPLN_ID
                    FROM TLS224_APPLN_CPC
                       WHERE CPC_CLASS_SYMBOL NOT IN ('G01N  33/74'))
            AND cpc3.APPLN_ID IN 
                (SELECT APPLN_ID
                      FROM TLS224_APPLN_CPC
                          WHERE CPC_CLASS_SYMBOL IN ('C07K  16/26', 'C07K2317/34', 'C07K2317/76'))
                ) cpc1
ON cpc1.APPLN_ID = p2.APPLN_ID
```

I am still a newbie to SQL so any help is appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your IN and NOT IN doesn't make sense.

if `CPC_CLASS_SYMBOL`  are in the first Group they are automatocally NOT IN your second

Your WHERE clause would only give you `APPLN_ID`  (and some more) the have these symbols and everything else is excluded.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. However, PATSTAT is a relational database and there are multiple entries associated with the same seed value. Every application has associated various cpc symbols. I need to obtain the applications that have associated a set of symbols A but that do not include a set of symbols B. Do you have any suggestion in that sense?

Comment: you need so for such question a [mre], as you only ask about in and NOT in asnwered your question., but for further help show please some more information

Answer (score 0):

The actual code might not work scince I could not test it but I think what you are intending to do is something like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p2.APPLN_ID
FROM (SELECT p1.APPLN_ID, p1.PUBLN_AUTH, YEAR(p1.PUBLN_DATE)
        FROM TLS211_PAT_PUBLN p1
            WHERE YEAR(p1.PUBLN_DATE) = 2008
                    AND PUBLN_AUTH = 'WO') as p2
Left JOIN (SELECT APPLN_ID
            FROM TLS224_APPLN_CPC
            WHERE CPC_CLASS_SYMBOL IN ('G01N  33/74')) as cpc_nottofind on p2.APPLN_ID = cpc_nottofind.APPLN_ID
Left Join(SELECT APPLN_ID
            FROM TLS224_APPLN_CPC
            WHERE CPC_CLASS_SYMBOL IN ('C07K  16/26', 'C07K2317/34', 'C07K2317/76'))
                ) as cpc_tofind on p2.APPLN_ID = cpc_tofind.APPLN_ID
Where cpc_nottofind.APPLN_ID is Null And cpc_tofind.APPLN_ID is Not Null
```

The first join is giving all appln_ids that are including the cpc-symbols you don´t want to search. The second join is given all appln_ids that are including cpc-symbols you would like to have.

The where clause in the last line is including all ids where the "not to find" cpc-classes are not found and where at least one of the "to find" cpc-classes is found.